# Unable to coordinate animation for both CSS styling and content on save of SPA field

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a SPA that is saving individual form fields.  I am trying to provide user feedback when the value has been updated by placing a green box around the field with the word "Saved" on the right side.  I have been able to place a box around the field and add a "Saved" text, but I can not get them to appear/disappear in an orderly fashion.  I suspect it is because I am trying to do both animation and translation and also adding/removing a class and not fully understanding this process as I am more a developer than a designer. Can someone point me in the correct direction, I would appreciate it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var self = this;

  $("#field1").on('change', function() {
    var el = $(this);

    el.addClass("saveIndClass");


    setTimeout(function() {
      el.removeClass("saveIndClass");
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```css
.saveField {
  borAder: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1px 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1px 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1px 1s ease-in-out;
}

.saveIndClass {
  border: 1px solid #5CBA49;
  padding: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.saveIndClass::before {
  content: "Saved";
  color: #5CBA49;
  font-size: 9px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px;
  right: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fade 1s linear;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <BR/>
  <form>
    <div id="field1" class="saveField">
      <select class="form-control input-xs">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="No">No</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </form>

</body>
```

One additional request is, what I have, seems to work in Chrome, but only partially works in Firefox ("Saved" shows on first change but not future ones).

Answer (score 0):

This example it works just fine, it remans just to add green border:

```
  <form>
    <div id="field1">
      <div class="text">
          <span>Saved</span>
          <select class="form-control input-xs">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </div>

    </div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  </form>

.saveField {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 2px;
  display: inline;
  border-radius: 5px;  
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1px 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1px 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1px 1s ease-in-out;
}

.text {  
  padding: 2px;
  border-radius: 5px; 
}

.text span {  
  opacity: 0;
  color: green;
  display: block;
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  var self = this;

  $("#field1").on('change', function() {
    var el = $(this),
        txtEl = el.find('.text span');

    txtEl.animate({"opacity": 1}, 2000, function(){
        txtEl.animate({"opacity": 0})
    });

  });
});
```

Hope this help you to close this quetion. Good luck ;)

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I am still not sure it is exactly correct.  It seems like the text and the border are not fading in and out at the same time.  The Text seems to disappear with the border still in place and then the border goes away abruptly rather than fading out.  The jsfiddle shows this behavior and also the Firebox issue.